# What's the Japanese equivalent of having a "F**k Buddy"?

Tags: word-requests

Does Japanese have a word for someone who's your "fuck buddy"? You know, someone decently attractive with whom you have all the sex of a relationship without all the romance and rituals.

Does Japanese have a decent equivalent? Or is this one of those concepts that's too esoterically Western to find in an Asian culture like that of Japan?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The concept definitely exists in Japan.

You can use the word セフレ, which comes from a portmanteau of the English loanwords **セ**ックス (sex) and **フレ**ンド (friend).

source: [http://www.weblio.jp/content/セフレ](http://www.weblio.jp/content/%E3%82%BB%E3%83%95%E3%83%AC)

Answer (score 8):

The other word which you want is やりとも.やる means "do sex" and とも means "friend". かきタレ also means that but this is slangy.